# ReactJS environment Setup Error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.output.path: The provided value "" is not an absolute path!
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! helloworldapp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the helloworldapp@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server --hot'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the helloworldapp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --hot
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs helloworldapp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls helloworldapp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/aakash/.npm/_logs/2017-04-12T09_51_55_188Z-debug.log
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - the `output.path` in your configuration file isn't set.

Comment: I'm doing environment setup from [ https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.html ] .
I have created folder structure same as said but i'm getting above configuration.output.path error

Comment: That link doesn't exist - did you mis-spell it? Either way, you should add your `webpack.config.js` to the question, as that's definitely where the issue lies.

Comment: ` var config = {
   entry: './main.js',
 
   output: {
      path:'./',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },
 
   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },
 
   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
    
            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

module.exports = config; `


My webpack.config.js file as above

Ref from: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.html

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says:

```
configuration.output.path: The provided value "" is not an absolute path!
```

Why that's displaying a blank string instead of the actual value of `output.path`, I have no idea - but either way, your configuration is wrong. The value of `output.path` *has* to be an absolute path, and you have yours set as a relative one.

The usual way people get around this is by importing the `path` module from Node, and using `path.join`, like so:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    /// ...

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "index.js"
    },

    // ...
};
```

However, since you're just trying to dump the output file in the root directory, you could just get away with doing this:

```
// no path import needed

module.exports = {
    // ...

    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "index.js"
    },

    // ...
};
```